# Como fazer um echo de um select DATEDIFF?

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz o código seguinte

```
$data_restante = "SELECT DATEDIFF(CURTIME(),$data) AS date";
$result_data_res = mysqli_query($conn, $data_restante);
$dado_data_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_data_res);
echo $dado_data_res['date'];
```

Mas não retorna nada. o que está errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `$data` deveria estar entre aspas:

```
"SELECT DATEDIFF(CURTIME(),'$data') AS date"
```

Mas também a variável não pode ser uma string literal. Antes você deve convertê-la em formato de data:

```
$data = "2018-02-01";
$data = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data));
```